# Stop RabbitMq listeners during run time

Tags: spring-integration

My beans/listeners are built using `IntegrationFlows`

ex.

```
  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow registerDevices() {
     return IntegrationFlows
        .from(adapter)
        .channel(channel)
        .get();
  }
```

there is such a way to stop listeners after something happens, endpoint call/event

`RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` does not work, because I'm not using `@RabbitListener`

There is the possibility to set `autostart up - false`, but then how to manipulate it nicely during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please, be careful when you choose tags for your questions over here. You concern so far really belongs to Spring Integration and has nothing to do with Spring AMQP. Although you are right: the lifecycle control really goes in the end to the `ListenerContainer` from Spring AMQP.

Anyway: the end-user API for your use-case is a part of Spring Integration logic.

See the second argument of that `from()`:

```
.from(adapter, e -> e.id("myAmqpAdapter"))
```

So, having that `id` yo are able to reach your `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter` (implement a `Lifecycle`) at runtime and stop & start it whenever you need.

See more in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-endpoints

And this pattern is also good to have on board:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus

Comment: thanks for the answer, appreciate the suggestion regarding tags :) by implementing lifecycle you meant, injecting a collection of IntegrationFlow beans and then invoking stop method on each of them?

Comment: No. Why is that? You wanted to stop only particular AMQP Inbound Channel Adapter. So, I gave you an example how to identify it. What you need is only to `@Autowire @Qualifier("myAmqpAdapter") Lifecycle amqpInboundChannelAdapter` in the service where you want to control its `stop/start`. I don't understand why you talk about a collection for `IntegrationFlow`...

Comment: Thought about that, because I wanted, for example, to stop/start all available inbound channels without knowing id's, you're of course right but now I need to inject all possible adapters in that service if I want to stop them all

Comment: Correct. You can inject them by type as list